# Xdg-Mime won't change default application for .xopp (Xournalpp) files

Tags: manjaro, xdg, xdg-open

I'm trying to change the default application for the filetype `.xopp`, which is a file for the xournalpp application. I currently ran the following commands:

```bash
xdg-mime query filetype 2022-06-09/note.xopp
```

which gave me: `application/gzip`. How can I make only the files that end in `.xopp` open in xournalpp? It works when I use a file browser, but when I run:

```bash
xdg-open 2022-06-09/note.xopp
```

it opens it in an unzipping program.

I'm currently using `Manjaro Linux`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me on KDE (but on Ubuntu) was to open "File Associations" window from the application launcher (or alternatively open "System Settings" and go to "File Associations" there), then:

- Create a new MIME type (the "+ Add..." button, bottom left)
- Choose "application" in the menu and give "xopp" as type name

You should now find a new "xopp" entry under the "application" types; choose it and

- In "Filename Patterns" click "+Add..." and input the "*.xopp" string
- In "Application Preference Order" click "+Add..." and choose Xournal++ app.
- You can also choose an icon by clicking on the white rectangle. Look for a xournal-related svg file in your system (in my case I chose `/snap/xournalpp/current/usr/share/xournalpp/ui/pixmaps/application-x-xopp.svg`)
- Click "Apply" and "OK"